# How to prove by double counting that $n^2 = 2\binom{n}{2}+n$ for all $n \ge 0$?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$, which means I want to find a way to count both sides. LHS is $1+2+3+ \ldots +(n-1)$, but I don't how that may help and how the proof should go on. Please help.

Comment: Maybe try induction? Although, not sure if this fits what you mean by double counting. Incidentally, by definition of the Binomial coefficient, $${n\choose 2}=1/2(n-1)n.$$

Answer (score 2):

RHS: you can think of $n \choose 2$ as picking two different numbers out of $1$ through $n$, where the order of the two numbers does not count.

Now, if the smaller number is $1$, then the larger one can be any of $2$ through $n$, which is $n-1$ options

If the smaller is $2$, then the second is any of $3$ through $n$, so that is $n-2$ options

Etc.

Total: $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1$

Comment: If the first number is $2$, why can't the second number be $1$? Your answer is somewhat misleading as it's implicitly assuming that you're ordering the $2$ numbers so the smaller one is first, which you can do as the order of choice is not important. I suggest you reword your answer to make this more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @johnomielan Thanks for the feedback ... i think my answr is indeed better now, thanks!

Comment: Your argument would be clearer if you said the smaller number rather than the first number.

Comment: @NSTaussig Quite! I’ll do exactly that, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $$ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$$

On the RHS you have $$\binom{n}{2}$$ which is the number of ways that you can choose two objects out of n distinct objects.

In order to choose two objects, first you pick one object out of $n$ and then you pick another object out of the remaining $n-1$, so you have $n(n-1)$ choices, but since there is no order involved you divide the result by $2$ to get the total number as $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You can represent $n^2 = 2\binom{n}{2}+n$ as
$$
(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{n \text{ times}})\cdot (\underbrace{1+...+1}_{n \text{ times}}) = 2\binom{n}{2}+n
$$
For every pair $(a,b)$, seen as "pick the $a$-th summand from the left brace, and the $b$-th summand from the right brace", we now get a summand $1$.

Now, as $\binom n2 $ counts sets $\{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$, you get two pairs out of each such set. Finally, you have to add all the tuples $(a,a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $i,\,j$ from $1,\,\,\cdots,\,n$ in one of $n^2$ ways. Of these, $n$ satisfy $i=j$, $\binom{n}{2}$ satisfy $i<j$, $\binom{n}{2}$ satisfy $i>j$.

Comment: Did you mean pick $(i, j)$?

Comment: @NFTaussig I suppose I could say "$i,\,j$ each from $1,\,\cdots,\,n$" or "$(i,\,j)$ from $\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\}^2$".

Answer (score 0):

> Combinatorial proof of the formula $$n^2 = 2\binom{n}{2} + n$$

We count the number of ways of assigning two different tasks to $n$ people if each task is to be performed by a single person if the same person may be assigned both tasks.

There are $n$ people who could be assigned each task, so there are $n^2$ possible assignments.

Either both tasks are assigned to the same person or they are assigned to two different people.

There are $n$ ways to assign both tasks to the same person.

If the two tasks are assigned to different people, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose which two people will be assigned the tasks and $2! = 2$ ways to assign the tasks to the selected people.  Hence, there are $2\binom{n}{2}$ ways to assign the two tasks to different people.

Hence, the number of ways of assigning the two tasks to $n$ people is
$$2\binom{n}{2} + n$$
Equating our two results yields
$$n^2 = 2\binom{n}{2} + n$$

> Combinatorial proof of the formula $$\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$

We count the number of two-element subsets of the $n$-element set $S = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1\}$.

There are 
$$\binom{n}{2}$$
ways to select a subset with two elements from a set with $n$ elements.

Let $k \in S$, where $k > 0$.  The number of two-element subsets of $S$ with larger element $k$ is $k$ since there are $k$ ways to choose an element smaller than $k$ in $S$.  Since the larger element can vary from $1$ to $n - 1$, the number of two-element subsets is 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$
Equating our two results yields
$$\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$